# Is it ok to have a `SendEmail` rack middleware or other such background job middlewares?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rack, eventmachine, goliath

I read rack middleware is for modifying the current request/response, but what about having a SendEmail middlewares which would look at `env['user_id']` to send emails.

Let's assume the entire process (request + sending emails) will be async.

Comment: Well, I've a Goliath app, where one endpoint was growing very complex. Its hard to test and maintain so I decided to cut it up. Original plan  was to have many endpoints and communicate between them via http, but was unable to do that. This was the second idea. Another idea is to use EventMachine queues, i.e. put the `user_id` into `SendEmail` queue and work that elsewhere. Mostly concerned with easy maintenance and testing at this point.

Comment: Adding the job to a queue is definitely a better option.

Comment: I think I tested Goliath wrong, so http idea is possible, is hitting '/send_email' via http a better option? I don't see very much info about EM Queues on the web aside from trivial examples, so not sure about them.

Comment: @sent-hil, pretty sure Andrew is talking about Resque or delayed_job queues (I certainly am) ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really want to do it in Goliath I'd suggest creating a plugin and doing it in there. Create a queue in the config and have the plugin pop items from the queue and send the mail.